# Multiple marginal plots with Seaborn jointgrid plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn, boxplot, jointplot

I'd like to draw a jointgrid plot with multiple marginal plots like below:

[image]

The reference code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
print(penguins['species'])

plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")

g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)
g.plot_marginals(sns.boxplot)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `stripplot` plots on the marginal axes, you could just add the `hue` parameter:

```py
g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)
g.plot_marginals(sns.stripplot, hue="species", dodge=True)
```

[image]

But `boxplot` does not currently handle `hue` with only one coordinate variable assigned, so you need to draw each marginal plot separately:

```py
g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", hue="species")
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)
sns.boxplot(penguins, x=g.hue, y=g.y, ax=g.ax_marg_y)
sns.boxplot(penguins, y=g.hue, x=g.x, ax=g.ax_marg_x)
```

[image]

Comment: In my case, it works if edit the lines like below:

Comment: sns.boxplot(data=penguins, x=g.hue, y=g.y, ax=g.ax_marg_y)
sns.boxplot(data=penguins, y=g.hue, x=g.x, ax=g.ax_marg_x)